# Dynamic form builder Form creation MySql DB structure

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I implemented Bootstrap Form Builder class to create dynamic form for site.so admin can easy create form with diffrent fields .I want to save each fields against the form and its type,value,id,class and its attr .What is the best practice or structure i should follow in creating the DB table.

Any reference will be great helpful

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO. Anyway, if doing this myself i would probably store the data as json, for flexabillty, as it seems unlikely you need to query against it (and some database engines have json query support now anyway).

Comment: Your correct.I got the json response but i need to query against these fields.And the whole project is based on MySQL and i can't change the DB at this time.

Comment: What kind of queries do you need to make against these fields? Also, mysql has native json columns and query support since v5.7

Comment: I need query against the values of these field that we can make different forms with different type of inputs .So i need to map the form its fields and its data(value,id,class ....). an my version is 5.0.11